# JAVA Pass individual dimensions of a 2D array as 1D arrays

Tags: java, arrays, loops, methods

I'm trying to check if each row of an array, and then each column contains duplicate values (latin rectangle check). I made a method that checks a 1D array, but I can't figure out how to pass a part of a 2D array into it. Here's my 1D array checking method:

```
public static boolean hasDuplicates(int [] inArray)
   {
      for(int i = 0; i < inArray.length; i++)
         for(int j = i + 1; j < inArray.length; j++)
            if(inArray[i] == inArray[j])
               return true;
      return false; 
   }
```

Here's my mess of a method that calls my previous method:

```
   public static boolean arrayChecker(int[][] inArray)
   {
      int [] splitRows = new int[inArray.length];
      int [] splitCols = new int[inArray[0].length];

      for(int row = 0; row < inArray.length; row++)   
      {
         for(int col = 0; col < inArray[0].length; col++)
            splitRows[col] = inArray[row][col];

         if(hasDuplicates(splitRows))
               return true;
      }

      for(int col = 0; col < inArray[0].length; col++)  
      {
         for(int row = 0; row < inArray.length; row++)
            splitCols[row] = inArray[row][col];

         if(hasDuplicates(splitCols))
               return true;
      }


      return false;
   }
```

I know the problem with it right now is that my splitRows and splitCols arrays don't reset values after each loop, so when it runs again it will check new values vs the old ones. I can't seem to find a way around it. I tried setting the arrays = null before the loop, but that clears out the size and screws it up even more.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Here's my call in my main method:

```
      if (arrayChecker(originalArray))
         System.out.println("Invalid");
      else
         System.out.println("Valid");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hasDuplicates(inArray[row])
```

Will pass 1d Array to `hasDuplicates`

Comment: Oh cool, I didn't know that worked. How would I pass a column through? Wouldn't using two [][] just a pass an address instead of an entire column?

Comment: @CoinBird: If you want pass 1st column then fetch 1st element from every row and create new array.